# I have to create new folder and copy or move the files to that folder and delete files using c#

Tags: office-365, office-365-develop-tool

I have to create new folder and copy or move the files to that folder and delete files using c#, in office 365.

Note.: I don't have install SharePoint 2010, I have to use CSOM or any other using C# only and not default credentials.

Answer (score 3):

### Create Folder via CSOM

The following example demonstrates how to create sub Folder

```
    public static Folder CreateFolder(Web web, string listTitle, string folderUrl)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderUrl))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Folder Url could not be empty");
        var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
        var folder =  list.RootFolder.Folders.Add(folderUrl);
        web.Context.Load(folder);
        web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
        return folder;
    }
```

> Note: the method is intended for creation of sub folder under root
>   folder

In case of nested folders please follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22010815/1375553) for a solution.

### Copy/Move Files via CSOM

Use [File.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.copyto%28v=office.15%29.aspx)  and [File.MoveTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.moveto%28v=office.15%29.aspx) methods to copy and move the file to the specified destination URL.

The below example demonstrates how to move files from one folder to another in Library

```
public static void MoveFiles(string url, string listTitle, string srcFolder,
        string destFolder)
    {
        using (var context = new ClientContext(url))
        {

            var srcList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
            var qry = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
            qry.FolderServerRelativeUrl = string.Format("/{0}",srcFolder);
            var srcItems = srcList.GetItems(qry);
            context.Load(srcItems, icol => icol.Include
                (i => i.FileSystemObjectType,
                    i => i.File));
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (var item in srcItems)
            {
                if (item.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.File)
                {
                    var destFileUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", listTitle, destFolder, item.File.Name);
                    item.File.MoveTo(destFileUrl, MoveOperations.Overwrite);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by default credentials, but the following will create a folder:

```
List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");
ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
itemCreateInfo.UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder;
itemCreateInfo.LeafName = "Folder Name";
ListItem newItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
newItem.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

If you're running this in an app, then you can use `TokenHelper` to create the `ClientContext`.  Otherwise you can create the context with the following:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(url);
String password = "password";
SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach(char c in password)
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com",securePassword);
```

Don't forget to dispose `clientContext`, or use a `using` block.